# Do you know of a paper or book clearly describing how to compute the parameters for a linear mixed-effects model from data

Tags: mixed-model

I need to write a computer program to estimate the fixed-effects and random-effects parameters for a linear mixed-effects model.  Is there a paper or book that clearly describes how to do this?  Can you please give me a bibliographic-like citation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this book presents all the necessary details that you need to implement a program to estimate the fixed-effects and random-effects parameters for a linear mixed-effects model from scratch:

[Generalized Linear Mixed Models: Modern Concepts, Methods and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A8SSAWO)

If you intend to use a software like R, you may find information in this tutorial:

[Linear Mixed Models](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych252/section/Mixed_models_tutorial.html)